# Google Map not visible in print preview in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, print-preview

For some reason Map is not visible in Print Preview in Google Chrome.

Here is the page (http://apexdemo.hami.net/property/1039-52th-ave-brooklyn-ny-41263/) where google map image is visible and working fine but when I press Ctrl + P (Print Preview) Google map is not visible. how to show image in print preview. As this is visible in main page.

Thanks in advance!